# Edit and test MVC frontend without database access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have an existing web project with MVC 5 that currently accesses a database to show listings and search results.

This project needs to be reskinned, which requires a large amount of frontend work.  But we're not sure how to let a developer do this without giving him the entire database.

Since we can't set up the database on his computer, is there an easy way to let him edit the pages (i.e. make changes to views and preview this in the browser with test data)?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Any kind of repository pattern in play? Or abstractions of the data-pulling mechanisms?

Comment: Is the frontend dev not allowed to see the data either? Or you just want to keep access to the db itself off limits?

Comment: We have repository classes but they call some stored procedures using Database.SqlCommand() so it's not purely object-based.

Our frontend is allowed see the data, but working via FTP is not an option and it would take too long to set up a test database on his machine.